# Performing different operations in Thread - android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-volley, timertask

I've this condition to write the server call that executes every 50ms.
The server call must be from volley.
But the difficulty i am facing is every server call has different urls and how to pass these different urls in thread so to call server every 50ms.?

Comment: You have a list of servers that you must call in sequence, one each 50ms, or you must call them all every 50ms?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to DDOS someone

Comment: I'm working on a board that will be controlled from mobile. So as per requirement, this board constant server calls will be made and these commands will differ as user presses the button on mobile application @RaduIonescu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in android, but this is what I could think of if you want to call different urls after 50ms. Please correct me if I am wrong :)

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    int i=0;
    final String[] urlArray = new String[]{"http://google.com","http://fb.com"};//your url array here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String currentURL= MainActivity.this.getNextURL();
                new HitWebService().execute(currentURL);
            }
        };
        worker.schedule(task, 50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private String getNextURL(){
        String currentURL= urlArray[i];
        if(i ==  urlArray.length){
            i=0;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
        return currentURL;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class HitWebService extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            //do whatever you want with respect to ui
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){
            HttpURLConnection connection=null;
            String stringUrl= params[0];
            try {
                URL url= new URL(stringUrl);
                connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                DataOutputStream outputStream=new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                String parameters = "initialise your parameters here, pass parameters also in params and access it like params[1]";

                outputStream.writeBytes(parameters);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    response.append(line);
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                return response.toString();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException malformedException){
                return malformedException.toString();
            }
            catch (IOException ioException){
                return ioException.toString();
            }
            finally {
                if(connection !=null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response){
            //do whatever you want here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but this did gave me a direction for what to do. Thanks. @sandeep-bhandari